# How to convert this data in to comma separated value in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below ;

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tempQeus](
    [EmpId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PlanId] [bigint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1872, 48)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1872, 60)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1872, 64)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1873, 49)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1873, 60)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1873, 64)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1874, 48)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1874, 60)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tempQeus] ([EmpId], [PlanId]) VALUES (1874, 65)
GO
```

I need the output to be like below with comma separated;

for each EmpId the corresponding planId should be in one column with comma separated

Expected output;

```
EmpId      PlanId

1872       48,60,64
1873       49,60,64
1874       48,60,65
```

I have no clue where to start and i'm new to SQL and using SQL version 2016.

Comment: Upgrade to a supported version of SQL Server and use `string_agg()`.

Comment: Why state *"using SQL version 2016"* and  tag [tag:sql-server-2008]? Either way, the linked duplicate tells you everything you need.

Comment: @GordonLinoff isn't `string_agg()` supported only on 2017 or higher? AFAIK, 2012 version is still supported...

Comment: @ZoharPeled . . . Yeah.  But if you are going to go to a supported version, you might as well go to a recent one.

Comment: SELECT  EmpID,STUFF((SELECT  ',' + PlanId
            FROM tempQeus EE
            WHERE  EE.EmpID=E.EmpID
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS listStr
FROM tempQeus E
GROUP BY E.EmpID                                                                                                           I tried this but receiving 'Error converting data type varchar to bigint.'